# How to list users and streams they flow to, within a team/project area?

Tags: rtc

I periodically have to generate a List of users and what streams they are flowing to. So :

```
user1 , stream1 , stream3 , stream4
user1 , stream1 , stream2 , stream4 , stream5
```

To accomplish this I generate a flow diagram for each stream and note the streams that each user is flowing to.

This is time consuming. Can this task be scripted ? This does not seem to be described in the RTC doc "Getting started with the Jazz SCM command line in Rational Team Concert"  : https://jazz.net/library/article/620

Answer (score 1):

The [RTC plain Java API](https://jazz.net/library/article/1229) could help, as in [this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/91050/how-to-list-all-outgoing-changesets-using-plain-java-api):

```java
IWorkspaceManager wm = (IWorkspaceManager)teamRepository.getClientLibrary(IWorkspaceManager.class);
IWorkspaceSearchCriteria criteria1 = IWorkspaceSearchCriteria.FACTORY.newInstance();
    criteria1.setKind( IWorkspaceSearchCriteria.WORKSPACES );
    criteria1.setExactName( INTEGRATION_WORKSPACE );
    criteria1.setExactOwnerName(INTEGRATION_WORKSPACE_OWNER);
    List<iworkspacehandle> workspaceHandles = wm.findWorkspaces(criteria1, Integer.MAX_VALUE, monitor);
    IWorkspaceHandle wh = workspaceHandles.get( 0 );
    IWorkspaceConnection workspaceConnection = wm.getWorkspaceConnection(wh, monitor);

    IFlowTable flowTable = workspaceConnection.getFlowTable(); 
    IFlowEntry flowEntry = flowTable.getCurrentDeliverFlow();
    IFlowNodeHandle streamHandle = flowEntry.getFlowNode();
```

One you have a `IFlowNodeHandle`, see [this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/113369/obtain-flow-target-for-workspace-using-api):

```java
IWorkspace fetchedFlowNode = (IWorkspace) repo.itemManager().fetchCompleteItem(flowNode, IItemManager.DEFAULT, monitor);
System.out.println(fetchedFlowNode.getDescription());
```